# How to join the two table in Laravel 5.4

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am learning Laravel 5.4. But I have stuck in one place.

I have two tables **coursenames** and **branchnames**.

**branchnames table contains:** id, branchname, course_id

**coursenames table contains:** id, coursename

coursename has a unique name, and course_id of branchnames has an id of coursename, which can be repeated.

**My BranchNameController is:**

```
public function index()
{
    $branchname = branchname::all();
    $coursename = coursename::all();
    return view('admin.branchname',compact('branchname','coursename'));
}
```

**branchname.blade.php is:**

```
<tbody>
   @foreach($branchname as $branchnames)
   <tr>
      <td>{{ $branchnames->branchname }}</td>
      <td>{{ $branchnames->course_id }}</td>
   </tr>
   @endforeach     
</tbody>
```

I want to show course name instead of **{{ $branchnames->course_id }}**. How it can be done?

**model branchname.php is:**

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class branchname extends Model
{
//
}
```

**model coursename.php is:**

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class coursename extends Model
{
//
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use Laravel relations to achieve this. Your branchnames course_id column belongs to course table.

Add the following relation in you branchname model:

```
public function course() {
    return $this->belongsTo(\App\coursename::class, 'course_id')
}
```

Then in you controller index function use:

```
public function index()
{
    $branchname = branchname::with('course')->get();
    $coursename = coursename::all();
    return view('admin.branchname',compact('branchname','coursename'));
}
```

Then in view you can show name as:

```
<td>{{ isset($branchnames->course) ? $branchnames->course->coursename : "" }}</td>
```

Comment: Thankyou. Its working. But what is the meaning of $branchname = branchname::with('course')->get();

Comment: I read the elequent relation :         $galleryalbum = vichar_gallery::find($id)->course;

Comment: May u provide any tutorial link for relationship, which is related to your answer.

Comment: You can read about relationship from here https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships

Answer (score 3):

try this
branchName model

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class branchname extends Model
{
  public function course(){
    return $this->belongsTo(coursename::class, 'coursename_id');
  }
}
```

// courseName model

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class coursename extends Model
{
  public function branch(){
    return $this->hasOne(branchname::class, 'coursename_id');
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

using `join` method in laravel  [see](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/queries#joins)

```
 public function index()
    {
        $branchname = branchname::join('coursenames','coursenames.id','=','branchnames.course_id')->select('coursenames.id as course_id','branchnames.branchname')->get();
        return view('admin.branchname',compact('branchname'));
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 $branchname = branchname::join('coursenames','coursenames.id','=','branchnames.course_id')->select('coursenames.id as course_id','branchnames.branchname')->get();
```

Now using Eloquent:

In the Branchname model

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class branchname extends Model
{

  // creating a one to many relationship with model coursename

  public function coursename(){

    return $this->hasMany('App\coursename');
  }

}
```

In the coursename model:

```
    <?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class coursename extends Model
{
   public function branchname(){

    return $this->belongsTo('App\branchname');

   }
}
```

In the controller:

```
public function index()
{
    $branchname = branchname::all();
    return view('admin.branchname')->with('branchname',$branchname);

}
```

In the view branchname.blade:

```
<tbody>
    @foreach($branchname as $branchnames)
     <tr>
      <td>{{ $branchnames->branchname }}</td>
      <td>{{ $branchnames->coursename->course_name }}</td>
     </tr>
    @endforeach     
</tbody>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But is is not laravel elequent way?

Comment: Answer by you,  is query builder?

Comment: Yes. Sorry for that :)

Comment: OK. No problem. Can U make it eloquent way. And I want to know which is better. Eloquent or query builder?

Comment: Here is the link for laravel model relationship tutorials:  [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=42l4nHl_aUM&index=10&list=PLillGF-RfqbYhQsN5WMXy6VsDMKGadrJ-)

Comment: (3/3) ErrorException
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'coursenames.branchname_id' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `coursenames` where `coursenames`.`branchname_id` = 2 and `coursenames`.`branchname_id` is not null) (View: F:\xampp\htdocs\millennium_alumni_laravel\resources\views\admin\branchname.blade.php)

Answer (score 0):

you can try this

--> **branchname.php (model)**

```
namespace App\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
class branchname extends Model
{
  public function course()
  {
      return $this->belongsTo(coursename::class,'course_id','id');
  }
}
```

--> **BranchNameController.ph**p

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use App\Model\branchname;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Model\coursename;

public function index()
{
   $branchname = branchname::orderBy('updated_at','DESC')->paginate(15);
    return view('branchname.branchname',['page'=>'Branchname','branchname'=>$branchname]);
}
```

--> **branchname.blade.php**

```
<tbody>
@foreach($branchname as $items)
<tr>
  <td>{{ $items->branchname }}</td>
  <td>{{ $items->course->id }}</td>
</tr>
@endforeach     
</tbody>
```